# django "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed." (one to many relationship)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Games(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    game = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = '__all__'

class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Games
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import models
from . import serializers
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class UserView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer

class CreateUser(APIView): # this works just fine
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = serializers.UserSerializer(data= request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            username = serializer.data.get('username')

            queryset = models.User.objects.filter(username)
            if queryset.exists():
                user = queryset[0]
                user.username = username

                user.save(update_fields=['username'])
            else:
                user = models.User.objects.create(username=username)
                user.save()
                return Response(serializers.UserSerializer(user).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            return Response({'BAD REQUEST': 'INVALID DATA'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class CreateGame(APIView): # this is causing problems
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = serializers.GameSerializer(data= request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            game = serializer.data.get('game')
            user = serializer.data.get('user')
            
            game = models.Games.objects.create(user=user, game=game)
            game.save()
            return Response(serializers.GameSerializer(game).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({'BAD REQUEST': 'INVALID DATA'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.UserView.as_view(), name='view'),
    path('user', views.UserView.as_view(), name='user-view'),
    path('game', views.CreateGame.as_view(), name='create-game')
]
```

> Basically I have 2 models, the User and Game model, I want there to be 1 user that has many games which is why the Game model has a foreign key attached to User, but for some reason it is causing problems in the APIView and returns a 405 not allowed error(at /game)... how can i fix this?

Comment: You did not make a POST request, but a GET request...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`APIView` you've implemented has only `post()` method and `get()` is unimplemented, therefore you receive such an error. You receive the error because `APIView` abstracts some parts of the `Request` and `Response` handling, but it won't do everything automatically unlike `ListCreateAPIView` and other [generic views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/).

```py
class CreateGame(APIView): # this is causing problems
    def post(self, request)  # here
```

Either change to `get()` if you want to use `GET` HTTP method or use `POST` HTTP method instead.

Or better, simply use the `ListCreateAPIView` and override the `post()` or [`create()` method](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createmodelmixin). That way you'll have only slight changes instead of custom `APIView`.